# Retrofit always calling onFailure even response is 200

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to call my API. I am very new to Retrofit and this is the reason why I am unable to find this error. I send a request to the API, API response is `200 OK` but retrofit calls the `onFailure` method. My API interface is as follows:

```java
public interface API {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<Login> login(@Query("user") String email,@Query("pass") String password, @Field("device key") String deviceKey);

}
```

and my call is:

```java
loginCall = MyApplication.getInstance().getAPI().login(username,password,deviceKey);
        loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {

                if(response.body() != null)
                {
                    Login login = response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failsssssssss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

And my model class is as follows:

```java
public class Login {
    String status;
    String Auth_Token;

    public Login(String status, String auth_Token) {
        this.status = status;
        Auth_Token = auth_Token;
    }
}
```

As far I understand this issue, there is a problem with my model class. My API returns two responses:

```
"{"status":"200","Auth_Token":"jhjsfbah71yb121t312hv"}"
```

```
"{"status":"500","Response":"Invalid Cardentials"}"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Retrofit reads the HTTP status, not the status within the JSON

Comment: what changes than i should do sir, should i change server side status as http status?

Comment: Are you logging the call? That might help to figure out the error

Comment: not actually but have debugged several times and not getting the main reason

Comment: inside `onResponse` log out `response.code()` to see what it is, your fix is likely serverside

Comment: thanks i will do work on server side to get it done

Comment: Please log error message in your `onFailure` method. To do this - replace `Failsssssssss` with `t.getLocalizedMessage()` and update your question with a logged exception.

Comment: Create getter and setter for fields in Login and make them private

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem with your server response.
Retrofit reads HTTP Status, So you have to make sure you sent it from the server. Retrofit is trying to read a response code 200 which is not available probably so it is calling on failure method.

Answer (score 4):

Using t.message() inside onFailure() reveals the mismatch in datatypes for json to model class, which causes this problem. just debug it via t.message() and change the datatype as suggested in the message, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
In my case, the problem was caused by casting the response to JSON format.
(The response I was getting was not in JSON format)
So to figure out the details, I ResponseBody the following way.

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = client.callTTS(request);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if(response == null)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Response is null");
        }else
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Response has contents");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by print_r($data) from my Api.Removing it solved my problem.

**OLD CODE**

```
  public function getNewsApi()
    {
            $data = $this->Db_Model->select_all_data('news');
            print_r($data);
            $response['result'] = isset($data) ? $data : '';
            $response['message'] = 'All data';
            $response['status'] = 'true';
            $response['code'] = '200';

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

**NEW CODE**

```
public function getNewsApi()
    {
            $data = $this->Db_Model->select_all_data('news');
            $response['result'] = isset($data) ? $data : '';
            $response['message'] = 'All data';
            $response['status'] = 'true';
            $response['code'] = '200';

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Hope this helps too.